# Dynkin indices for Spin(8)

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

I'm working with a Spin(8) gauge theory. I need to know the Dynkin indices for the $\mathbf{8}_v$, $\mathbf{8}_s$, and adjoint representations.

By "Dynkin index" I mean $T(R)$ where
$$\text{Tr}(T^a_R T^b_R) = T(R)\delta^{ab}$$
for $T^a_R$ the generators in representation $R$.

Edit: If it is the same as SO(8), would I be correct in saying $T(\mathbf{8}_v)=T(\mathbf{8}_s)=8$ and $T(\mathbf{adj})=4$?

Comment: “Group theory for unified theory building” by Slansky has tables of this stuff. Table 36 seems to show that the adjoint rep (dim 28) of SO(8)  has index 48.

Comment: [Yamatsu](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.08771) is another resource. It agrees than the index of the adjoint is greater by a factor of 6, but it is using a different definition of the index.

Comment: If you have *Mathematica*, the [LieART](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.6379) package is another resource.